# Alternative to polling interrupt flag from main loop?

Tags: c++, interrupt, teensy

I am using an ISR, which is written to be as minimal as possible:

```cpp
volatile bool interrupt1{};

void ISR1() {
    interrupt1 = true;
}
```

The interrupt is handled by polling the interrupt1 variable in `loop()`:

```cpp
if (interrupt1 == true) {

// Do stuff

interrupt1 = false;
}
```

Even though the interrupt signal coming in on the gpio isn't polled, the method described above is instead polling the interrupt variable from `loop()`.

As an alternative to the above, is it possible to use some kind of push logic on the software side whenever an interrupt occurs, instead of continuously polling the interrupt variable? I hesitate to handle the full task from the ISR, as it's performing a lot of things.

What are my options here?

Comment: `if (interrupt1 == true)`  the `true` is redundant ... use  `if (interrupt1)` instead

Comment: `volatile bool interrupt1{};` - what are the braces for?

Comment: @NickGammon This is an empty braced-init-list, I think blindly added or because of source code guidelines.

Comment: @Nick Gammon Uniform initialization

Comment: @jsotola I know it's redundant, but i prefer the verbosity in this case

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, you may reach the limits of what Arduino can do here, and you may be better off using an RTOS and threads (and queues or locks or mutexes to wait until the condition is met). On some platforms Arduino is built on top of an RTOS and there are libraries to expose that. No idea if that applies to the Teensy (though that possibly depends on which model).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the task is pretty short and time sensitive, your best option is to
put it in the interrupt handler.

If the task is big and not too urgent (like: it could well wait for a
millisecond or so), your approach of polling the flag within `loop()` is
the best one, provided the main program is non-blocking.

If the task is both big and urgent... you may have a difficult problem.
You could try both approaches and see which one works best. Or you may
try to split the task into a top half (short and urgent) and a bottom
half (long but not so urgent). The interrupt handler would then perform
the top half and set a flag, whereas the main loop would poll the flag
and perform the bottom half.

**Edit**: for a short discussion on the top half / bottom half approach,
see the first paragraphs of [this article on Linux kernel
development](https://litux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch07lev1sec1.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Last portion is particularly interesting. I might be able to refactor the responsibilities for a better tradeoff between timing and heavy lifting, so to speak...

Comment: It can be tricky to think about what part of a task is "urgent". The ISR handler should take care of anything that will _go wrong_ if you wait (like anything that's necessary to prepare the hardware for another event, if it arrives before you've finished with this one.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged it Teensy: You could also reduce the priority of the interrupt, so that it can be interrupted by higher priority interrupts. Thus you can implement interrupts with longer durations without blocking important system functions.

Here is an example using the GPT1 and GPT2 timers running at different priorities:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "TeensyTimerTool.h"

using namespace TeensyTimerTool;

PeriodicTimer loPrioTimer(GPT1);
PeriodicTimer hiPrioTimer(GPT2);

void onLowPrioTimer() // some long task running from interrupt with low prio
{
    Serial.printf("  Start low prio isr @t=%d ms\n", millis());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Serial.printf("    lowPriority task %d\n",i);
        delay(10);
    }

    Serial.println("  Stop low prio isr");
}

void onHiPrioTimer() // high prio, will interrupt the low prio isr
{
    Serial.printf("high priority @t=%d ms\n", millis());
}

void setup()
{
    while (!Serial) {}

    loPrioTimer.begin(onLowPrioTimer, 500ms); // GPT1
    hiPrioTimer.begin(onHiPrioTimer, 50ms);   // GPT2

    NVIC_SET_PRIORITY(IRQ_GPT1, 128); // lowest prio
    NVIC_SET_PRIORITY(IRQ_GPT2, 16);  // high prio
}

void loop()
{
}
```

which prints:

```
high priority @t=1057 ms
high priority @t=1107 ms
high priority @t=1157 ms
high priority @t=1207 ms
high priority @t=1257 ms
high priority @t=1307 ms
high priority @t=1357 ms
high priority @t=1407 ms
high priority @t=1457 ms
high priority @t=1507 ms
  Start low prio isr @t=1507 ms
    lowPriority task 0
    lowPriority task 1
    lowPriority task 2
    lowPriority task 3
    lowPriority task 4
high priority @t=1557 ms
    lowPriority task 5
    lowPriority task 6
    lowPriority task 7
    lowPriority task 8
    lowPriority task 9
high priority @t=1607 ms
  Stop low prio isr
high priority @t=1657 ms
high priority @t=1707 ms
high priority @t=1757 ms
high priority @t=1807 ms
high priority @t=1857 ms
high priority @t=1907 ms
high priority @t=1957 ms
high priority @t=2007 ms
  Start low prio isr @t=2007 ms
    lowPriority task 0
    lowPriority task 1
    lowPriority task 2
    lowPriority task 3
    lowPriority task 4
high priority @t=2057 ms
    lowPriority task 5
    lowPriority task 6
    lowPriority task 7
    lowPriority task 8
    lowPriority task 9
high priority @t=2107 ms
  Stop low prio isr
high priority @t=2157 ms
high priority @t=2207 ms
high priority @t=2257 ms
high priority @t=2307 ms
```

This shows that the high priority timer (running at 50 ms interval) intercepts the low priority ISR which runs every 500 ms for about 100 ms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've never used interrupt priority. Wanna elaborate?

Comment: @Erik  added an example

Comment: Very interesting, thank you!

Comment: What if an interrupt of the same kind occurs? For example, if it was counting something, wouldn't it miss a count increment (it presumably isn't a reentrant ISR)?

Comment: What baud rate was used for 'Serial'?

Comment: If an interrupt of the same kind occurs while the first one is serviced it will set the interrupt flag again and the isr will be called again (unless you delete the flag at the end of the ISR). However, this can not handle more than one interrupt request while an isr runs. Here some information about the ARM Nested Interrupt System: https://microcontrollerslab.com/nested-vectored-interrupt-controller-nvic-arm-cortex-m/

Comment: Baud rate: there is no such thing as a baud rate for "usb-Serial" aka CDC. The data will always be transmitted with the full USB bandwidth. (Up to some 20MByte/s on a T4x). Also, Serial.begin() is just some compatibility function. It used to be empty. These days it provides some waiting for connection code, I prefere a simple while(!Serial){}